# Write SQL query to get all records based on value from another table (not join case)

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, `Account` and `Tracking`
`Account` table has an `ID` (int data type)
`Tracking` table has `AccountID` (FK) and `Status` (string data type)

I want to write MySQL query.

My goal is to get all accounts whose theirs `ID` number bigger than the biggest ID number recorded in `Tracking` table

OR

all accounts that have `Status` "Failed" in Tracking table.

Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Account a
        JOIN Tracking t
            ON a.ID = t.AccountID
WHERE   (a.ID > (SELECT MAX(AccountID) FROM Tracking)) OR
        (t.Status = 'Failed')
```

you need a regular join but use a subquery to get the "ID larger than" part of your `OR` statement

Comment: Change `WHERE   (ID >` to `WHERE   (a.ID >` and we're good :)

Answer (score 1):

I am considering the question as 2 different queries.
You can use sub query, if you don't want to use join.

**Query1:**

```
select * from Account where id > (select max(AccountID) from Tracking);
```

**Query2:**

```
select * from Account where id in (select distinct AccountID from Tracking where status = "Failed");
```

Comment: I'm looking for a single query. But I've tested it and this is also correct :) Thanks a lot. It may useful for people who are looking for this type of answer